# Full text search on all stored procedure definitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a couple of stored procedures and I want to search through them and return the name of any procedure that does not contain a keyword `nolock`. I successfully achieve this with the query below.

```
Select 
    name as [storedprocedures with no lock] 
from 
    databasename.sys.storedprocedures 
where 
    name not in (Select name as [storedprocedures with no lock] 
                 from databasename.sys.storedprocedures 
                 where OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%(nolock)%')
```

However, I realized the above return a procedure that has no keyword nolock at all. However,the purpose of the project is to return the name of any procedure that the key word `with nolock` is not mentioned after every table name in a `select` statement. The above query does not work for a procedure that suppose to have more than one `nolock` but have one.

Please is there any where I can make it search till the end of the procedure and return the stored procedure name where a table "A" is mentioned and a keyword  `with nolock` does not surpass it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all: I would ***NEVER*** just blindly use `with (nolock)` on every `SELECT` - do you **TRULY** understand the implications? Do you truly understand what this is doing? And do you understand what you might get yourself into? In order to find out if every table name (including tables in JOINs) has a ` with (nolock)` you would have to use a SQL parser - and that's not something that's avaialble from within T-SQL, you'd have to use some other external language/programming system to achieve this....

Comment: THank you sir. I am not goin gto use it blindly. THe problem is it was not applied where required. And therefore we want to go through and see and edit where necessary.

Comment: @marc_s can you please suggest the way i should go about this then  ? If using the parser is necessary , can you please elaborate may be with a link or something ?